Is it possible for a function to narrow down types in the function body?
I have a function which looks as so:
interface Message {
  id: string;
  content: string;
  created_at: Date;
  updated_at: Date;
  priority: 'low' | 'medium' | 'high'
}

function merger<T extends Message, K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K], data: T) {
  if (key === 'content') {
    return `${data[key]}${value}`
  }
  return value;
}

// ...
const merge = mergeWith(merge, current, incoming);

The problem, however, is typescript is not able to infer the type correctly from the key. I would expect that if K is content, it would be able to infer T['content'] would be of type string
Is there a way to solve this?
Here's what I tried. I don't really like it
interface Message {
  id: string;
  content: string;
  created_at: Date;
  updated_at: Date;
  priority: 'low' | 'medium' | 'high'
}

function isContent<T extends Message, K extends keyof T>(key: K, data: T): T[K] is string {
  return key === 'content';
}

function merger<T extends Message, K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K], data: T) {
  if (isContent(key, value)) {
    return `${data[key]}${value}`
  }
  return value;
}

// ...
const merge = mergeWith(merge, current, incoming);


"K is content, it would be able to infer T['content'] would be of type string" the value of key is "content", the type of K is the union of all the keys of T unless it's a compile-time constant. That intuition you have doesn't hold if key can be an arbitrary key of T at runtime, because the compiler can't see the future.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! • What is mergeWith? What is merge, current, incoming? Where is the type not being inferred from the key in that code? Is there an error somewhere? Should we hover over the type of some value to see it? Please [edit] to make the code a [mre] which clearly shows your problem without distractions when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs. • You've probably run into ms/TS#33014 but it's not 100% clear how to address it without a [mre].
